# 3-Point Compactification of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Does there exist a compactification $X$ of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with the following properties?

- $X$ is compact
- $X$ is Hausdorff
- $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is dense in $X$
- $X \setminus (\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}) = \{\infty_1, \infty_2, \infty_3\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is compact and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is closed but not compact, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_1\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is closed but not compact and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is compact, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_2\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is closed but not compact and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is closed but not compact, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_1, \infty_2, \infty_3\}$

I was thinking of taking $X$ to be quotient of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ where we identify $[0,1) \times \{1\}$ to the single point $\infty_1$, $\{1\} \times [0,1)$ to the single point $\infty_2$ and $(1, 1)$ to $\infty_3$ and then embed $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as $[0,1) \times [0,1)$, but I don't think the resulting space is Hausdorff.

The point of this is that we can informally express a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being Cauchy as "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $n, m \to \infty$". If we have a compactification with the above properties, we can formally express this as "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $(n, m) \to \infty_3$".

Comment: Density property requires $\infty_1 \in \overline{\mathbb R_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb R_{\geq 0}}$, but your last property requires opposite (take $A = B = \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$).

Comment: @mihaild Thanks. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you ask for 3-point compactification? Do you already know that it does not have a 2-point compactification? In fact, if a space has a Hausdorff n-point compactification, it also has a Hausdorff m-point compactification for each $m \le n$.

Comment: @Ulli I ask for a 3-point compactification because this seems most natural in the context I'm considering and I want to require additional properties of the new points at infinity. I didn't know the fact about compactifications with less points.

Comment: Well, as said, it doesn't exist. If you already know, that there isn't a 2-point compactification, the proof would be easier. But anyway, I'm afraid that right now I don't have the time to write it down. Might be some other user can do that?

Comment: The negative answer to [the analogous question for $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845882/491450) also implies a negative answer to this, since if $X$ was such a compactification of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, then $Y = \operatorname{cl}_X \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ would be such a compactification of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such Hausdorff compactification.  To see this, note that the complement of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ has precisely one non-relatively-compact connected component. As a result, if there are finitely many "points at infinity" (points added in the compactification), there must only be $1$.

To see why this is so, observe that if $\infty_1,\dots,\infty_n$ are the added points, then by Hausdorff we can find neighborhoods $U_k\ni\infty_k$ for  $k=1,\dots,n$, where $U_k$ are disjoint.  Then $(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})\backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_k$ is compact, with a complement having at least $n$ non-relatively-compact components.  We therefore have $n=1$.

Comment: Why do you take $\overline{U_k}$ and not just $U_k$?

Comment: @Smiley1000 fair point.  The truth is I was in a hurry and got mixed up and knew that it wouldn't hurt to make the closures disjoint, so I did it to be safe, to be sure the two complementary components were really separate - but I was being silly, since open disjoint sets are by definition separated.  I edited to fix this.