# 3-Point Compactification of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Does there exist a compactification $X$ of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with the following properties?

- $X$ is compact
- $X$ is Hausdorff
- $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $X$
- $X \setminus (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) = \{\infty_1, \infty_2, \infty_3\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite and $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_1\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is infinite and $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_2\}$
- If $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is infinite and $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, then $\overline{A \times B} = (A \times B) \cup \{\infty_1, \infty_2, \infty_3\}$

I was thinking of using the following construction: Let $N = \{1 - \frac1n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Let $N' = N \cup \{1\}$. Take $X$ to be the quotient of $N' \times N'$ where we identify $N \times \{1\}$ to the single point $\infty_1$, $\{1\} \times N$ to the single point $\infty_2$ and $(1, 1)$ to $\infty_3$ and then embed $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ as $N \times N$, but I don't think the resulting space is Hausdorff.

The point of this is that we can informally express a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being Cauchy as "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $n, m \to \infty$". If we have a compactification with the above properties, we can formally express this as "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $(n, m) \to \infty_3$".

Comment: Context? Why do you care about this? I'm guessing it's homework

Comment: @FShrike This isn't homework. I came up with this question when thinking about how to formalize the following notation for a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being Cauchy: "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $n, m \to \infty$". If we are able to obtain a compactification of the above form, then we could formally write "$d(a_n, a_m) \to 0$ for $(n, m) \to \infty_3$".

Comment: That is crucial context to include in your post. You should always include relevant motivational details; there is perhaps no interesting answer to the statement in your question as it stands, but there could be a good answer to the thing you *really* want to know (similar to XY problem).

Comment: BTW: if you are interested in compactifications with finite reminder, it might be helpful to read this old paper of [Magill](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315952?seq=1). You have to register at JSTOR, but it's free.

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, I've expanded that paragraph.

Comment: @Ulli Thanks, I've adapted the topological terminology to the specific case of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I've now realized that $\mathbb{N}^* \times \mathbb{N}^*$ is already the appropriate compactification. We have $(n_i, m_i) \to (\infty, \infty)$ iff $\forall \infty \in U \subseteq \mathbb{N}^* \text { open}, \forall \infty \in V \subseteq \mathbb{N}^* \text { open} \exists j \in I \forall i \geq j: (n_i, m_i) \in U \times V$ iff $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall l \in \mathbb{N} \exists j \in I \forall i \geq j: n_i \geq k, m_i \geq l$ iff $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \exists j \in I \forall i \geq j: n_i, m_i \geq k$, and this is precisely what we mean when we talk about Cauchy sequences.

Comment: That does not work, the set $$(\mathbb N^* \times \mathbb N^*) - (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) =\left( \{\infty\} \times \mathbb N^{*} \right) \cup \left( \mathbb N^* \times \{\infty\}  \right)$$ has infinitely many points, not three points.

Comment: It would make sense to link to [your previous related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845727).

Comment: My guess is no, unless you're willing to give up Hausdorff. Compare with https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000185/ which is semi-Hausdorff but compacts are not closed. It is missing your $\infty_3$ but you could add one with neighborhoods which are of the form $[n,\infty)\times[m,\infty)\cup\{\infty_3\}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think I was a little unclear - I understand that $\mathbb{N}^* \times \mathbb{N}^*$ does not fulfill the conditions laid out in my question, which is why I have not posted it as an answer. But it does give us exactly the right formalization of "$n, m \to \infty$" - it's just "$(n, m) \to (\infty, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{N}^* \times \mathbb{N}^*$"

Comment: @FShrike: While I agree that it is nice to include some mention of the motivation, I think the question is interesting in its own right, and diluting it with *too much* detail (in this case, more than one sentence...) about the motivation would not improve it.

Comment: @tomasz I can only repeat that it's possible their intended purpose (find a non-metric purely topological encoding of a Cauchy sequence) has a good answer even if their attempted *solution* (finding such a compactification of $\Bbb N$) does not. So they're more likely to get help for the question they actually care about, if they include the question they actually care about!

Comment: @FShrike: Yes, but that is a separate question.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to really think about this but fyi, if you're taking a quotient and you want it to be Hausdorff (or even $T_1$, for that matter), remember the preimage of each point under the quotient map must be closed, which they are not in your proposed example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there can be no such compactification.

To see why, note first that if $U$ is a neighborhood of $\infty_1$, then there cannot be an infinite set $B$ with $(\{n\}\times B)\cap U=\emptyset$, otherwise taking $A=\{n\}$ we would have $\infty_1\notin \overline{A\times B}$.  Thus any neighborhood of $\infty_1$ must include a set of the form $U_f:=\{(m,n)\mid n\geq f(m)\}$ for some function $f\colon \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$.

The same argument with the coordinates interchanged shows that any neighborhood of $\infty_2$ must include a set of the form $V_g:=\{(m,n)\mid m\geq g(n)\}$.  Then by the Hausdorff condition there are $f$ and $g$ and some neighborhood $W$ of $\infty_3$ with $U_f$, $V_g$, and $W$ pairwise disjoint.

We now construct sets $A$ and $B$ as follows.

Let $(a_1,b_1)\in U_f$.  Then proceed by induction, assuming at each stage $n$ we have picked $a_1,\dots, a_n$, and $b_1,\dots b_n$, so that if $A_n=\{a_1,\dots, a_n\}$, and $B_n=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$, then $A_n\times B_n\subseteq U_f\cup V_g$.

Having picked $A_n$ and $B_n$ in such a fashion, we pick some $a_{n+1}$ large enough so that $(a_{n+1},b_k)\in V_g$ for each $k\leq n$.  Then we pick some $b_{n+1}$ large enough so that $(a_k,b_{n+1})\in U_f$ for each $k\leq n+1$.  Thus $A_{n+1}\times B_{n+1}\subseteq U_f\cup V_g$ as well.

We continue for all $n$, and so obtain sets $A=\bigcup_n A_n$ and $B=\bigcup_n B_n$, such that $A\times B\subseteq U_f\cup V_g$.  But then $(A\times B)\cap W=\emptyset$, so since $W$ is a neighborhood of $\infty_3$, $\infty_3\notin \overline{A\times B}$, contradicting the fact that $A$ and $B$ are infinite.